# MySQL User() return only so many characters

Tags: mysql, character

I am using the User() to populate a table which returns something like (admin@localhost).

How would I return

1) only the items to the left of the @ (if possible)

and

2) only the first 10 characters (if something like AnnaMariaSmith@localhost, just return AnnaMariaS)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT LEFT(USER(), LOCATE('@',USER()) - 1)
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4459)

If you want only the first 10 characters of the result above, just another `LEFT` function:

```
SELECT LEFT(LEFT(USER(), LOCATE('@',USER()) - 1), 10)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was about to press edit to remove the portion about the left 10, but you beat me to doing that!  The second function which provides the first 10 to the left of @ is just what I was looking for :)

Comment: You could also use `substring_index(user(), '@', 1)` which is a bit clearer IMO.